# THREE.ParametricGeometry(func ,slices,stacks) the func execute times

Tags: javascript, three.js

three.js:version:0.121
when I run this code,

```
new THREE.ParametricGeometry( func, 200, 10)

var func(u, v, point){
console.log(u,v)
}
```

result:

```
0 0
0.00001 0
0 0.00001
0.005 0
0.0049900000000000005 0
0.005 0.00001
0.01 0
0.00999 0
0.01 0.00001
0.015 0
0.01499 0
0.015 0.00001
0.02 0
0.01999 0
0.02 0.00001
0.025 0
...
```

it look like a bad slice

when i run the similar code in
**version:0.74**

```
new THREE.ParametricGeometry( func, 200, 10)

var func(u, v){
console.log(u,v)
}

0 0
0.005 0
0.01 0
0.015 0
0.02 0
0.025 0
0.03 0
0.035 0
0.04 0
0.045 0
0.05 0
0.055 0
0.06 0
0.065 0
···
```

So why this happen, the 0.121 version cannot show the result well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional calls of the parametric function were introduced with `r85` in order to fix a normal computation bug. You can read more about this in the following PR: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11056

Apart from the normal data, other vertex information are not affected by this fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is in the ParametricGeometry function, what will this function do in the silence, it`s not like the version 0.73,that in my code, make the func execute 200*10 times, in the new version, I can not understand the slice and stack